# Delay in countdown timer

Tags: android, countdowntimer, android-wake-lock

I have a countdown timer that runs in a service and after the timer is up it launches an activity. The activity will wake up the screen display regardless if there is a lock screen or not. The problem is that once the timer is up it takes amount 13-27 extra seconds to launch the activity and turn on the display. I don't know if it has to do with the countdown timer or I'm not turning on the screen display properly. This is my code any help will be appreciated.

### Service Countdown

```
    public class CountDownTime extends CountDownTimer {


        /**
         * @param millisInFuture    The number of millis in the future from the call
         *                          to {@link #start()} until the countdown is done and {@link #onFinish()}
         *                          is called.
         * @param countDownInterval The interval along the way to receive
         *                          {@link #onTick(long)} callbacks.
         */
        public CountDownTime(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {



            long millis = millisUntilFinished;

            int progress = (int) (millisUntilFinished/1000);
            // this is the format which reads the time data from the user and makes it readable
            hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));



            CountDownAct.timeTextView.setText(hms);
            CountDownAct.timeProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
            Log.i("CountDownService", hms);

//            if(progress <= 1000){
//                CountDownAct.timeProgressBar.setProgress(0);
//                Intent goBack = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), alarmtimefinished.class);
//
//          goBack.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//            goBack.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
//
//
//            startActivity(goBack);
//
//            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {




            CountDownAct.timeProgressBar.setProgress(0);
//            Intent intent = new Intent();
//            intent.setAction("com.personalproject.peter.timerapp.CUSTOM_INTENT");
//            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//          intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
////
//            sendBroadcast(intent);
            Intent goBack = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), alarmtimefinished.class);

          goBack.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            goBack.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);


            startActivity(goBack);


//            CountDownService.startService = true;
//



        }




    }
```

### Wakeup activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarmtimefinished);


        CountDownService.startService = true;
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        blink();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.extreme_clock_alarm);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
}
```

Comment: Are you using a WakeLock?

Comment: No would I need to if I am using window manager

Comment: It looks like you are only using the windowmanager in your Activity, but nothing is keeping the CPU awake if the Service is running. So the coundown in your Service without a CPU wakelock could be delayed by your device falling asleep. https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Comment: Try recording the time consumed by the delay timer, from beginning to end, so we can rule out one of the possibilities. (and confirm Frank's suspicions)

Comment: I recorded the time and everything runs properly if connected to the debugger, there are no delays;however, if the device is not connected then there is a delay in waking the device